# CSS / Firefox / Mac - Weird vertical scrolling behavior inside div

Tags: css

I have a very weird problem.  This ONLY affects Firefox on Mac, using the trackpad (so far as I know), but inside the div that is supposed to be horizontal scrolling only, you are able to scroll vertically too.  There seems to be some extra "padding" below the 2nd "`container`" div which you can see if you change "`height`" to "`min-height`" in `.container` (this will show up on all browsers).  All I'm trying to accomplish is to have multi-layered divs (the colored stack in the 2nd container div) "stack" on top of each other, using `position: relative`, but it seems to create extra, unwanted "padding" that I'm unable to get rid of.  Both Chrome and IE do not exhibit this behavior.

```
<style>    
#scrolling_div {
    border:2px solid black;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width:400px;
}

.container { border:1px dotted black;height:150px;margin:5px }
.other { width:100px }
#stack1,#stack2,#stack3 { height:150px;width:100px; }
#stack1 { background-color:red;top:-300px;margin-left:60px;position:relative;z-index:1 }
#stack2 { background-color:green;top:-150px;margin-left:30px;position:relative;z-index:2 }
#stack3 { background-color:blue;top:0px;margin-left:0px;position:relative;z-index:3 }
</style>

<div style='float:left;clear:right'>some text</div>
<div id='scrolling_div'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="stack3"><div style='margin-left:90px'>3</div></div>
                <div id="stack2"><div style='margin-left:90px'>2</div></div>
                <div id="stack1"><div style='margin-left:90px'>1</div></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style='float:left;clear:left'>some text</div>
```

Or you can play with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/bAzND/

Comment: I think you reversed horizontally and vertically in your description.

Comment: you're right, i did.  it's been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution to my dilemma.  In case anyone else runs into this issue in the future, the solution was to change all the "`stack`" divs from `position:relative` to `position:absolute`, remove the `top` attributes, then add `style='position:relative;width:160px'` to the `.container` `<div>` of the stack.  The `width` must be a fixed value.

Here is the code:

```
<style>    
#scrolling_div {
    border:2px solid black;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width:400px;
}

.container { border:1px dotted black;height:150px;margin:5px }
.other { width:100px }
#stack1,#stack2,#stack3 { height:150px;width:100px; }
#stack1 { background-color:red;margin-left:60px;position:absolute;z-index:1 }
#stack2 { background-color:green;margin-left:30px;position:absolute;z-index:2 }
#stack3 { background-color:blue;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;position:absolute;z-index:3 }
</style>


<div style='float:left;clear:right'>some text</div>
<div id='scrolling_div'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container" style='position:relative;width:160px'>
                <div id="stack3"><div style='margin-left:90px'>3</div></div>
                <div id="stack2"><div style='margin-left:90px'>2</div></div>
                <div id="stack1"><div style='margin-left:90px'>1</div></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="container"><div class="other">test</div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style='float:left;clear:left'>some text</div>
```

Here is the fixed code example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChSfE/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using firefox on os x and it doesn't do that for me.

Firefox version is 3.6.13; OS X is 10.6.6. I'm on a macbook 2,1.

Comment: ahh. maybe it only affects the newer macbooks then.  I have the same Firefox version, same OS, but MacbookAir3,1 (the new one that came out Oct 2010)

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it has to do with the multitouch touchpad? Though I couldn't imagine why.